# Aerospike - change storage type and size

Tags: aerospike

I'm just starting to learn about aerospike and thinking about the storage type for my application. Right now there is not too much data, so I'm plannning to use
`storage-engine device` with `data-in-memory true`.

However, should the size of the data increase in the future, would it be possible to change the settings to store only the indexes in RAM (remove `data-in-memory true`)? Would I need to do some kind of "database migration" or just comment out the line in config and restart the service?

Same question about `filesize` and `memory-size` parameters - if I increase these settings, should I somehow "resave" the data on disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For data-in-memory true, you can simply change to false and restart the asd daemon. Rolling restart will work (one node at a time), so no down time.

memory-size is actually dynamically configurable: [see doc](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#memory-size)

filesize would require an asd daemon restart, one node at a time.